# SELECT records from two tables where rows might not present in the second table (related to LEFT JOIN)

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have two tables - **Module** and **Access**.

**Module** - master table having list of modules.

**Access** - mapping of users and modules with respective rights (if user has rights to the respective module value of **HasAccess** will be 1 and if user does not have rights either the value of **HasAccess** will be 0 or the row will not be present)

**Requirement** -
I need a list of all the module names with respective rights for a particular user. (tricky part - it is not necessary all the modules will be present in the mapping table for a particular user as per the structure of **Access** table, as expained above)

Please review my query, it is working fine and is covering all the scenarios as well. I would like to know if there is a better way other than this or if you find any issues with my approach.

```
-- Table Module
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Module') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE #Module

CREATE TABLE #Module (
    [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Name] VARCHAR(20)
    )

INSERT #Module (
    [ID]
    ,[Name]
    )
VALUES (1, 'Module 1')
    ,(2, 'Module 2')
    ,(3, 'Module 3')
    ,(4, 'Module 4')
    ,(5, 'Module 5')

-- Table Access
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Access') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE #Access

CREATE TABLE #Access (
    [ID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #Module([ID])
    ,[UserName] VARCHAR(20)
    ,[HasAccess] BIT
    )

INSERT #Access (
    [ID]
    ,[UserName]
    ,[HasAccess]
    )
VALUES (2, 'User 1', 1)
    ,(3, 'User 2', 1)
    ,(4, 'User 2', 0)
    ,(4, 'User 1', 0)
    ,(5, 'User 1', 1)

-- List of modules and respective access for 'User 1'
DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(20) = 'User 1'

SELECT #Module.[Name] AS [Module]
    ,ISNULL(#Access.[HasAccess], 0) AS [Access]
FROM #Module
LEFT JOIN #Access ON #Access.[ID] = #Module.[ID]
    AND #Access.[UserName] = @UserName
```

Content of Table **Module** -

[image: Content of Table Module]

Content of Table **Access** for user - 'User 1'-

[image: Content of Table Access for user - 'User 1']

**Result** (List of modules and respective access for 'User 1') -

[image: List of modules and respective access for 'User 1']

Comment: Looks fine except for the last isnull(access.username...) part. Not sure why you’re using isnull here?

Comment: Thanks @Marko, and yes it feels like ISNULL is not required here, I will validate with a few examples and update.

Comment: Look fine. But suggest to put the filtering #Access.[UserName] = @UserName to the WHERE clause.

Comment: @YHTAN Actually we can't do that. Let me try to explain problems with that approach. 1. If we shift "#Access.[UserName] = @UserName" to the WHERE, it won't return "Module 1" and "Module 3" as there are no corresponding rows with "User 1" in the "Access" table. 2. If we use "ISNULL(#Access.[UserName], @UserName) = @UserName" in the WHERE, it won't return "Module 3" as there is corresponding row at all in the "Access" table with the same.  And that's where LEFT JOIN does the trick, that's why putting the condition with LEFT JOIN only.

Comment: Not that it’s not required, but it’s actually wrong as it can return wrong results in case you have null values in the access.username column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` as a subquery:

```
select m.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from #access a
                          where a.id = m.id and a.username = 'User 1' and
                                a.HasAccess = 1
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as has_access
from #modules m;
```

Comment: Looks like an issue in your approach, it will give value of HasAccess 1 for "Module 4", as value is present in the Access table but with value 0. Need to add condition "and [HasAccess] = 1" in your subquery. Also, can you give an idea if it is better in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1):

@Amit11794, Your approach is correct if you want result for specific user which you will pass as hardcoded value or in a variable.

However, if you want results for all users at once from single query, you can use below approach.

```
SELECT #Module.*,users.UserName, isnull(#Access.HasAccess ,0) as HasAccess
FROM #Module
cross join (select distinct Username from #Access) users
left join #Access on #Module.id = #Access.id and users.username = #Access.UserName
```

Result set

```
ID          Name                 UserName             HasAccess
----------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------
1           Module 1             User 1               0
2           Module 2             User 1               1
3           Module 3             User 1               0
4           Module 4             User 1               0
5           Module 5             User 1               1
1           Module 1             User 2               0
2           Module 2             User 2               0
3           Module 3             User 2               1
4           Module 4             User 2               0
5           Module 5             User 2               0
```